# Android - Can't Get swf To Work In My Web App

Tags: android, html, flash

I have a simple html/javascript based Android app that loads with the following code:

```
public class myActivity extends DroidGap {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty( "splashscreen", R.drawable.splash );
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 1000);
}
```

I have an embedded .swf that works fine if I load the index.html in the Android browser but will not load in the app.

HTML:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="book.swf" width="800" height="600">
    <param name="quality" value="high">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
    <param name="swfversion" value="8.0.35.0">
      <h4>Content on this page requires a newer version of Adobe Flash Player.</h4>
      <p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" width="112" height="33" /></a></p>
</object>
```

What do I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable plugins for your `WebView` with

```
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
```

If you are targetting Android 3.0+ you'll also need to add

`android:hardwareAccelerated="true"`

to the application manifest to get the Flash content to display correctly.

Comment: Right direction but I used the following to get it to work:

`mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);` Along with the hardware acceleration bit.